# Unable to push code to github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

I tried to push my code to github by using the following commands:

```
git remote add https://github.com/user/sample_app.git

git push origin master
```

And got the following error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/sample_app.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'non-fast forward'
section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

To see whether the error is at the remote I entered:

```
git pull
```

and got the following error:

```
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/sub1010/sample_app.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Why can't I push my code to github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding ssh repo and not http repo as such

```
git remote rm sample_app
git remote add git@github.com/user/sample_app.git
```

Comment: Yuriy: I tried what you suggested and got the following error on typing "git remote rm sample_app",    error: Could not remove config section 'remote.sample_app'    @MrDanA:  I will accept answers only if they work for me

Comment: open up your .git/config file and remove the remote section manually

Answer (score 0):

Github has **detailed instructions** on setting up a repository and ensuring you can connect with it.  Links: [Github Setup](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) and [Github Create A Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo)